# How to select id with max date group by category in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

For an example, I would like to select id with max date group by category,
the result is: 7, 2, 6

```
id  category  date
1   a         2013-01-01
2   b         2013-01-03
3   c         2013-01-02
4   a         2013-01-02
5   b         2013-01-02
6   c         2013-01-03
7   a         2013-01-03
8   b         2013-01-01
9   c         2013-01-01
```

May I know how to do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

This is a perfect use-case for [**`DISTINCT ON`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) - a Postgres specific extension of the standard `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (category)
       id  -- , category, date  -- any other column (expression) from the same row
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY category, date DESC;
```

Careful with descending sort order. If the column can be NULL, you may want to add `NULLS LAST`:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

`DISTINCT ON` is simple and fast. Detailed explanation in this related answer:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

For big tables with many rows per `category` consider an alternative approach:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Optimize groupwise maximum query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244026/optimize-groupwise-maximum-query/24377356#24377356)

Comment: Seems great but are you absolutely sure this is guaranteed to work every time?

Comment: @Tixel: Absolutely. Follow the links for more details.

Answer (score 25):

Try this one:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT category, MAX(date) AS MAXDATE
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY category
) t2
ON T1.category = t2.category
AND t1.date = t2.MAXDATE
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/144a9/96)

Comment: There is another option using the rank() window function.

Comment: @user1735921: You will get all columns from Table1. You can choose whichever you want.

Answer (score 17):

Another approach is to use the `first_value` window function: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7a145/14

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  first_value("id") OVER (PARTITION BY "category" ORDER BY "date" DESC) 
FROM Table1
ORDER BY 1;
```

... though I suspect hims056's suggestion will typically perform better where appropriate indexes are present.

A third solution is:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "category" ORDER BY "date" DESC) AS rownum
  FROM Table1
) x
WHERE rownum = 1;
```