# Select rows based on last date

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table named `Course` in a Postgres database:

[image: sample data for table Course]

How can I select rows which have course name with latest date? I mean if I have two same course names for one ID, I should only show the latest one as the below result.

Simply, I want only to show the latest row per ("ID", "Course Name").

[image: desired result]

And what if I have two date columns in table `Course`, which are `StartDate` & `EndDate` and I want to show the same based on `EndDate` only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select id with max date group by category in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914098/how-to-select-id-with-max-date-group-by-category-in-postgresql)

Comment: Thank you for asking this.  GREAT example.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, to get *unique rows for a defined set of columns*, the preferable technique is generally [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("ID") *
FROM   "Course"
ORDER  BY "ID", "Course Date" DESC NULLS LAST, "Course Name";
```

<sup>Assuming you actually use those unfortunate upper case identifiers with spaces.</sup>

You get *exactly one row* per `ID` this way - the one with the latest known `"Course Date"` and the first `"Course Name"` (according to sort order) in case of ties on the date.

You can drop `NULLS LAST` if your column is defined `NOT NULL`.

To get unique rows per `("ID", "Course Name")`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("ID", "Course Name") *
FROM   "Course"
ORDER  BY "ID", "Course Name", "Course Date" DESC NULLS LAST;
```

There are faster query techniques for *many* rows per group. Further reading:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: What if I have two date columns in `Course` table, which are `StartDate` & `EndDate` and I want to show the same based on `EndDate` only.?

Comment: @Aan: `... ORDER BY "ID", "Course Name", "EndDate" DESC NULLS LAST` to get the row with the latest `"EndDate"`. Basically, order by as many columns (or expressions) as you want. Make it unambiguous or get an arbitrary pick from qualifying peers. I also added the `DISTINCT ON` columns to `ORDER BY` as required, those were missing in my first draft.

Comment: upvoted! works well if you have a desc index like (id, date desc) but if you have (id, date) it is slow, i am assuming this is because the index operates in 2 levels having id at the first level and then doing a date lookup inside, what if the index was (date, id) would that mean date desc wont be required?

Comment: @PirateApp: An index on `(date, id)` would be hardly useful. You need `id` first. Follow the link in the answer for more. Also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39599/3684

Comment: Just be aware that this is not a good answer if you've got 16GB of records in the database.

Comment: @Owl: The size of the table is not the deciding factor. *Data distribution* is. For few duplicates, `DISTINCT ON` is typically fastest. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34715134/939860 Depending on data distribution and setup, there may be much faster techniques: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT "ID", "Course Name", MAX("Course Date") FROM "Course" GROUP BY "ID", "Course Name"
```

Comment: This works just fine, as long as there are no additional columns.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ID, CourseName, CourseDate, 
      MAX(CourseDate) OVER (PARTITION BY COURSENAME) as MaxCourseDate
FROM Course) x
WHERE CourseDate = MaxCourseDate
```

Here the MAX() OVER(PARTITION BY) allows you to find the highest CourseDate for each Course (the partition) in a derived table.  Then you can just select for the rows where the CourseDate is equal to the maximum Coursedate found for that Course.

This approach has the benefit of not using a GROUP BY clause, which would restrict which columns you could return since any non-aggregrate column in the SELECT clause would also have to be in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c."Id", c."Course Name") 
    c."Id", c."Course Name", c."Course Date" 
FROM (SELECT * FROM "Course" ORDER BY "Course Date" DESC) c;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  course
GROUP BY id,course name
order by course_date desc
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax. Try it. (MySQL might accept it, breaking the standard.)