# In Postgres, how do I select rows from my table with the most recent date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm using Postgres 9.5.  I have a table with a few columns ...

```
 crypto_currency_id | integer                     |
 price              | integer                     |
 last_updated       | timestamp without time zone |
```

There could be multiple entries for the crypto_currency_id .  My question is, how do I select only the most recent entries for each unique crypto_currency_id in the table?  So for instance, if my table contained the entries

```
crypto_currency_id        price         last_updated
=====================================================
2                         50             2017-06-01
2                         52             2017-07-01
3                         500            2017-01-01
```

I would want the query to return two rows, which would be

```
2                         52             2017-07-01
3                         500            2017-01-01
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select records based on last date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027881/select-records-based-on-last-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way in Postgres is `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (crypto_currency_id) t.*
from t
order by crypto_currency_id, last_updated desc;
```