# Getting this group by and max query to work

Tags: postgresql, max, groupwise-maximum

I have the following table `players` with an:

```
ID;color;race;score
1;"red";"elf";400
2;"blue";"elf";500
3;"green";"elf";300
4;"blue";"elf";200
5;"red";"elf";700
6;"red";"troll";100
7;"blue";"troll";400
8;"green";"troll";500
9;"red";"troll";400
10;"yellow";"troll";1000
11;"red";"nord";900
12;"green";"nord";100
13;"yellow";"nord";500
14;"blue";"nord";7000
```

I want per race, the maximum score and the color and ID of that player. Like this

```
elf 700 red 5
nord 7000 blue 14
troll 1000 yellow 10
```

The first two column I can get with:

```
select category,max(score)
from players
group by category;
```

But I'm unable to add the color and ID of that player. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select id with max date group by category in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914098/how-to-select-id-with-max-date-group-by-category-in-postgresql)

Comment: We don't know your column names but why wouldn't the following just work: `select category,max(score), max(id), max(color)
from players
group by category;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RANK` function:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY race ORDER BY score DESC) AS r
  FROM players
)
SELECT race, score, color, id
FROM cte
WHERE r = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/409272)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦════════╦════╗
║ race  ║ score ║ color  ║ id ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬════════╬════╣
║ elf   ║   700 ║ red    ║  5 ║
║ nord  ║  7000 ║ blue   ║ 14 ║
║ troll ║  1000 ║ yellow ║ 10 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩════════╩════╝
```