# SqlAlchemy group_by and return max date

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table such has

```
identifier date        value
A          2017-01-01  2 
A          2017-01-02  1
A          2017-01-03  7
B          2017-01-01  2 
B          2017-01-02  7
B          2017-01-03  3
```

I am trying to select the max date of each identifier such as  I get :

```
identifier date        value
A          2017-01-03  7
B          2017-01-03  3
```

thank you

Comment: This is a very common question and has spawned its own tag: [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. Try searching a bit. Solutions can be a bit DB specific, so please at least provide that information.

Comment: @IljaEverilä  I saw that, but there was no equivalent for sql alchemy (python equivalent)

Comment: I know that to be untrue. Here's a Postgresql solution for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069023/sqlalchemy-show-only-latest-result-if-a-join-returns-multiple-results, though it was missing the tag. It's also rather straightforward to implement plain SQL solutions in SQLA.

Comment: @IljaEverilä not sure where you see a group by in the question you are referring to. My SQL skills are very poor (full disclosure), it`s not always easy to incorporate a half similar solution and make it work

Comment: Nowhere as a clause, because it uses a Postgresql specific DISTINCT ON ... ORDER BY combination to achieve greatest n per group, efficiently. It's true that searching for SQL solutions is daunting, if not familiar with the terminology.

Comment: @IljaEverilä see, you are teaching me something.

Comment: For future and on the subject of teaching, don't fall in the trap of "XY problem", where you think something is a solution to a problem and then ask about that something, instead of asking about the problem itself. For example here a left join would work as well, not just a (inner) group by query.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Using a subquery:

```
SELECT t1.identifier, t1.date, t1.value FROM table t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT identifier, MAX(date) maxdate
    FROM table
    GROUP BY identifier
) t2
ON t1.identifier = t2.identifier AND t1.date = t2.maxdate;
```

In SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, and_

subq = session.query(
    Table.identifier,
    func.max(Table.date).label('maxdate')
).group_by(Table.identifier).subquery('t2')

query = session.query(Table).join(
    subq,
    and_(
        Table.identifier == subq.c.identifier,
        Table.date == subq.c.maxdate
    )
)
```

Comment: @Ruben Flam-Shepherd don't change the code; put a comment instead or your own answer

Answer (score 13):

With ORM you could use [`over`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over) function that is actually is a window function:

```
session \
    .query(Table, func.max(Table.date)
           .over(partition_by=Table.identifier, order_by=Table.value))
```

It returns a tuple (table_instance, latest_datetime). `order_by` is optional in this case.

The [same](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#window-functions) with SQL Expressions.

Comment: Doesn't work on sqlite3

Answer (score 2):

In SQLAlchemy core, it can be achieved using the following code -

```
import sqlalchemy as db

query = db.select([
    TABLE.c.identifier,
    db.func.max(USERS.c.date),
    TABLE.c.value,
]).group_by(TABLE.c.identifier)

result = engine.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

in orm you may write it almost as you would in mysql

```
result = session.query(Table,func.max(Table.date)).group_by(Table.identifier)
for row,i in result:
    print(row.date,row.value,row.identifier,i)
```