# SQLAlchemy - Get most recent child from every parent

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here's my situation. I have to tables

**Parent**

| id | other |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |
| 4 | ... |

**Children**

| id | parent_id | time_created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-11-17 13:18:49 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-11-17 13:47:05 |
| 3 | 2 | 2022-11-18 12:00:22 |
| 4 | 2 | 2022-11-18 16:06:17 |

What I would like to do, using SQLAlchemy in Python, is to retrieve the most recent **Children** for every parent. The result of the query would return Children with IDs 2 and 4 since they are the most recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for constructing the query in SQL, the cleanest way to achieve this is to use [Postgre's `DISTINCT ON` feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (parent_id) *
FROM Children
ORDER BY parent_id, time_created DESC;
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57254089/3738870), this could be mapped to the following SQLAlchemy code:

```py
latest_children = Children.query.\
    distinct(Children.parent_id).\
    filter_by(**filter_by_query).\
    filter(*queries).\
    order_by(Children.query, Children.time_created.desc()).\
    all()
```