# selects the last item by date

Tags: sql, datetime, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 types of items, 1000118500 and 1000438300 and I would like to know how to bring only the last item by the newest date.

so I would have only 2 lines, the newest ones

```
id item       created
1  1000438300 2018-10-26 00:43:30
2  1000438300 2018-10-16 00:44:02
3  1000118500 2018-10-13 00:41:27
4  1000438300 2018-09-26 00:47:28
5  1000118500 2018-08-09 00:40:09
6  1000438300 2018-07-12 12:05:37
7  1000118500 2018-06-28 20:06:24
8  1000118500 2018-06-28 20:06:07
```

could anyone help?
I'm using MariaDB

Comment: I uploaded an image and didn't upload it, I posted some lines

Comment: Great, most people here want lines, not images!

Comment: And listen @peter, with great power comes great responsibility :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the MAX function

```
SELECT item, MAX(created)
    FROM table
GROUP BY item
```

or see this post : [How to select id with max date group by category in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914098/how-to-select-id-with-max-date-group-by-category-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with a subquery to get the latest row per `item`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where created = (select max(t1.created) from mytable t1 where t1.item = t.item)
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `(item, created_at)`.

Comment: Yes, but you use an unnecessary subquery, didn't you ?

Comment: @coytech: the subquery retrieves that latest date per item, so it is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE_NAME] ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think he wants 1 results by item not for all the table

Comment: Incorrect. OP wants the last from each item. Mentioned specifically that 2 rows need to be returned

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `created` is a DateTime column, select what you want and order it by the date in descending order, then limit the result to 1 row, that will be the row with the newest date

```
select item 
from tablename
where id = 1000438300
order by created desc
limit 1
```