# How do I find the unique column value with maximum date consideration in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

For Example

| product_id | costhead_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1020209 | 1000105 | 2020-04-01 08:58:15 |
| 1020209 | 1000182 | 2021-11-24 11:27:40 |
| 1020209 | 1000183 | 2021-12-19 16:19:55 |
| 1020210 | 1000105 | 2020-04-01 08:58:15 |
| 1020210 | 1000182 | 2021-11-24 11:27:40 |
| 1020210 | 1000183 | 2021-12-20 16:19:55 |

I need a unique `product_id` with a maximum `date`. Required value like below

| product_id | costhead_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1020209 | 1000183 | 2021-12-19 16:19:55 |
| 1020210 | 1000183 | 2021-12-20 16:19:55 |

Comment: The question seems to be a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914098/how-to-select-id-with-max-date-group-by-category-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on(product_id) *
from table_name
order by product_id, date desc
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0c28be69486ecd877d671a82466c775b)